# How to call event handler, when a new class is added to any <li> element in a list?

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I'm current creating a wizard. for the wizard tab in can be in 3 states "current", "completed", "upcoming".

I would like to know how to trigger an event when a html element has its state changed.

e.g.

```html
<ul role="tablist">
    <li class="current">STEP 1</li>
    <li class="upcoming"> STEP2</li>
    <li class="upcoming">STEP 3</li>
    <li class="upcoming">STEP 4</li>
</ul>
```

So example a  user is CURRENTLY ON STEP1. when user clicks on step2. step1 will have its state replaced from "current" to "completed" and step 2 "upcoming" to "current"..

```html
<li class="complete">STEP 1</li>
<li class="current"> STEP2</li>
```

etc

because i'm using a 3rd party js file.. I 'm very reluctant to go through 800 lines of code creating triggers everytime a class is added to

element. So how can trigger an event, or watch, when a new class is added to any of the

I am using knockoutjs by the way, but i am new to it.

ViewModel

```
function CreateQuoteRequestViewModel(addresses, counterMessger) {


var _packageHeight = ko.observable("");
var _packageWidth = ko.observable("");
var _packageLength = ko.observable("");
var _packageVolume = ko.observable("");
var _packageWeight = ko.observable("");

function AddItemShowDisplay()
{
    $('#AddItem').animate({
        opacity: '1'
    },1000);

    _disableInputElement(false);
}
   .. other code

return {
     PackageHeight: _packageHeight,
    packageQuantity: _packageQuantity,
    PackageWidth: _packageWidth,
    PackageLength: _packageLength,
    PackageVolume: _packageVolume,
    packageWeight: _packageWeight,

   // and other code

}
```

calling viewModel

```
          var viewModel = new CreateQuoteRequestViewModel(array, counterMessger);  
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: Show your view-model.

Comment: At the moment I don't i have no direct bindings to any of the li element. I have a clientside view Model using Knockoutjs

Comment: I did refer to your Knockout (client-side) view model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to watch for changes on the DOM element.

Example from the docs:

```
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector('#some-id');

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log(mutation.type);
    });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
observer.disconnect();
```